# Help deciphering this Fatal Error (Java)

Tags: windows, swing, java, access-violation

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x762a76d0, pid=4072, tid=2984

 JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [ole32.dll+0x376d0]
```

Error Log: http://pastebin.com/zpBst6W1

Comment: When does the error occur? During launch? Some operation?

Comment: It occurs when I use the Open File operation built into my application. I'm not sure how helpful that is...

Comment: `it occurs when I use the Open File` then why there `sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.addNativeDropTarget()J+0
j  sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.addDropTarget(Ljava/awt/dnd/DropTarget;)V+9
j  java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.addNotify(Ljava/awt/peer/ComponentPeer;)V+60`

Comment: I'm sorry. What exactly are you pointing out? I don't really know what that snippet of my error means?

Comment: better would be post here shoth code that demonstrated your problem maybe is platforms rellated and then you can find that as Bug, really everything is shots to the dark

Comment: Strangely enough. I shut down my computer for the night.  When I came back this morning, I cannot get the error to present itself again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 3 says your program failed in the `AWT-EventQueue-0` thread, also called the [event dispatch thread (EDT)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). The execution stack trace starts in line 111, and builds up. At line 47, in the package `sun.awt.windows` and class `WComponentPeer`, the method `addNativeDropTarget()` attempted to call into the shared library, `ole32.dll`, failing at entry `CoUnmarshalInterface`. The rest describes the processor state at the time.

This can happen if the shared library is not the one expected by the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). You may need to check your installation.

Comment: I see that once time before (forgot when, where..) that genereted one example sucked from some of Code???Example???depots??? +1

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm fairly new to Java. What would you recommend I do to attempt to fix this issue?

Comment: @Matt: That is one [frequently recommended](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/reinstalling.html) approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Java 6 that is still open:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=e5f1f1011daf96ffffffffdd154dd2e731150?bug_id=6967456

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6967456?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel