# how to analyze jvm crash dump with .pdb file and .dll

Tags: java, dump, pdb-files

I encountered java crash dump from running java process that using jni native library. 
I have a dll and a pdb file of native library emitting crash dump. 
but i don't get exact section where cause jvm crash dump.

I read this blog.
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html

But i don't get how to read crash dump file. is there any good articles or tutorial

to read stack and crash dump. I thought If i have a pdb file ,I can get a exact function name and line number which make jvm crash dump.

Comment: See also [Help deciphering this Fatal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6671689/230513).