# The Swing project crashed

Tags: java, swing, matlab

In the java project I called a MATLAB project. I can run the project in the Console (The runtime is over 5 seconds), but when I run it in the GUI(Swing) part, it crashed with the following report. Please HELP me! Thank you.

I think the problem of mine is similar as this one.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/251694 . However, I don't get the idea of it.

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x65a83427, pid=2864, tid=4760
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jvm.dll+0x3427]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0840d800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4760]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000164

Registers:
EAX=0x00000002, EBX=0x0840d8e8, ECX=0x0840d7c0, EDX=0x00000002
ESP=0x0a6de4d4, EBP=0x0a6de4d8, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x082e0ca0
EIP=0x65a83427, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0a6de4d4)
0x0a6de4d4:   00000000 0a6de4fc 65b483e0 00000000
0x0a6de4e4:   00000006 082e0ca0 0840d8e8 00000000
0x0a6de4f4:   082ea3c0 00000000 0a6de518 786a1463
0x0a6de504:   0840d8e8 082e0ca0 0840d800 180942f8
0x0a6de514:   180942f8 0a6de554 0a84a460 0840d8e8
0x0a6de524:   0a6de55c 0a6de564 00000007 78e6a575
0x0a6de534:   0a6de534 180942f8 0a6de564 18100630
0x0a6de544:   00000000 180942f8 00000000 0a6de564 

Instructions: (pc=0x65a83427)
0x65a83417:   64 01 00 00 5e 5d c3 cc cc 55 8b ec 56 8b 75 08
0x65a83427:   c7 86 64 01 00 00 05 00 00 00 83 3d 58 ce d6 65 


Stack: [0x09ee0000,0x0a6e0000),  sp=0x0a6de4d4,  free space=8185k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jvm.dll+0x3427]
C  [jvm.dll+0xc83e0]
C  0x786a1463
j  java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Float.<clinit>()V+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Float.<clinit>()V+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.util.HashMap.<init>(IF)V+56
j  java.util.HashMap.<init>(I)V+4
j  sun.misc.SoftCache.<init>(I)V+26
j  java.lang.Thread.<clinit>()V+28
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x0840d800 JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4760]

Other Threads:
  0x08363c00 VMThread [id=1460]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 14784K, used 263K [0x10080000, 0x11080000, 0x12080000)
  eden space 13184K,   2% used [0x10080000, 0x100c1ec8, 0x10d60000)
  from space 1600K,   0% used [0x10d60000, 0x10d60000, 0x10ef0000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x10ef0000, 0x10ef0000, 0x11080000)
 tenured generation   total 49152K, used 0K [0x12080000, 0x15080000, 0x18080000)
   the space 49152K,   0% used [0x12080000, 0x12080000, 0x12080200, 0x15080000)
 compacting perm gen  total 32768K, used 518K [0x18080000, 0x1a080000, 0x1c080000)
   the space 32768K,   1% used [0x18080000, 0x18101a00, 0x18101a00, 0x1a080000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00e20000 - 0x00e4f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x76f80000 - 0x770bc000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x76db0000 - 0x76e84000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75190000 - 0x751da000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x768e0000 - 0x76980000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75ae0000 - 0x75b8c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76cf0000 - 0x76d09000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76c40000 - 0x76ce1000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x770e0000 - 0x771a9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x754f0000 - 0x7553e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x754e0000 - 0x754ea000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76d10000 - 0x76dad000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x74050000 - 0x741ee000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f77000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x768c0000 - 0x768df000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75410000 - 0x754dc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x659c0000 - 0x65a7e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x65a80000 - 0x65da8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x70ab0000 - 0x70ab7000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x755d0000 - 0x75605000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x770d0000 - 0x770d6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x738d0000 - 0x73902000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x770c0000 - 0x770c5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x68180000 - 0x6818c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x68160000 - 0x68180000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x659a0000 - 0x659b3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x6b490000 - 0x6b5d2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\awt.dll
0x75540000 - 0x755cf000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x757c0000 - 0x7591c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x73ac0000 - 0x73ad3000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x73db0000 - 0x73df0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x6c530000 - 0x6c539000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Spigot\Search Settings\wth.dll
0x70ac0000 - 0x70b63000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCR90.dll
0x10000000 - 0x1007c000     E:\Program Files\DigitalPersona\Bin\DpoFeedb.dll
0x74720000 - 0x74737000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75110000 - 0x7511b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x75060000 - 0x7506c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x04380000 - 0x043db000     E:\Program Files\DigitalPersona\Bin\DpoSet.dll
0x69370000 - 0x69533000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x745c0000 - 0x745c9000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6c140000 - 0x6c146000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x68bf0000 - 0x69369000     C:\Windows\system32\nvd3dum.dll
0x74020000 - 0x74045000     C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll
0x76aa0000 - 0x76c3d000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x752a0000 - 0x752c7000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x753f0000 - 0x75402000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x75bf0000 - 0x7683a000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x70d50000 - 0x70dd4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
0x61d90000 - 0x61dba000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x656f0000 - 0x65704000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x74b70000 - 0x74bac000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x74b40000 - 0x74b46000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x656e0000 - 0x656ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x72e30000 - 0x72e61000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\t2k.dll
0x75010000 - 0x7505c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x76e90000 - 0x76f13000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x06eb0000 - 0x07048000     C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
0x73ee0000 - 0x73fd5000     C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
0x73420000 - 0x73441000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x76840000 - 0x76885000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x6e740000 - 0x6e76e000     C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll
0x73140000 - 0x7314a000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x70580000 - 0x70592000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x716c0000 - 0x716c8000     C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
0x75070000 - 0x75099000     C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x716e0000 - 0x716f4000     C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x6d960000 - 0x6d977000     C:\Windows\System32\davclnt.dll
0x6cda0000 - 0x6cda8000     C:\Windows\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x74960000 - 0x7496f000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x701f0000 - 0x701fb000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x74b30000 - 0x74b39000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x71f30000 - 0x72168000     C:\Windows\system32\wpdshext.dll
0x73c20000 - 0x73db0000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17825_none_72d273598668a06b\gdiplus.dll
0x6dde0000 - 0x6de69000     C:\Windows\system32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
0x75270000 - 0x7529d000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x752d0000 - 0x753ed000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75180000 - 0x7518c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x72d90000 - 0x72dcf000     C:\Windows\system32\audiodev.dll
0x61640000 - 0x618a7000     C:\Windows\system32\WMVCore.DLL
0x72b10000 - 0x72b4d000     C:\Windows\system32\WMASF.DLL
0x6e9c0000 - 0x6e9f1000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x6cd70000 - 0x6cd92000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x73990000 - 0x73a8b000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x00990000 - 0x009a7000     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt.14.dll
0x6fc90000 - 0x6fd7b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
0x7c3a0000 - 0x7c41b000     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\MSVCP71.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\MSVCR71.dll
0x6e950000 - 0x6e9ba000     C:\Windows\System32\cscui.dll
0x6e940000 - 0x6e949000     C:\Windows\System32\CSCDLL.dll
0x6e8d0000 - 0x6e940000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x74f50000 - 0x74f69000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x088a0000 - 0x08a06000     E:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\nativemcl.dll
0x7ad60000 - 0x7adb2000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmx.dll
0x7ac90000 - 0x7ad5b000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libut.dll
0x76890000 - 0x768ba000     C:\Windows\system32\imagehlp.dll
0x7b4d0000 - 0x7b4ef000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\LIBEXPAT.dll
0x70cb0000 - 0x70d4b000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\MSVCR80.dll
0x7b040000 - 0x7b117000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icuuc36.dll
0x7a820000 - 0x7a824000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icudt36.dll
0x7a830000 - 0x7a83c000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icuio36.dll
0x7aaf0000 - 0x7abb2000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icuin36.dll
0x70a20000 - 0x70aa7000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\MSVCP80.dll
0x78680000 - 0x78692000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\zlib1.dll
0x08240000 - 0x082be000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mclmcr.dll
0x79710000 - 0x79746000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mcr.dll
0x7a840000 - 0x7a857000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\iqm.dll
0x7adc0000 - 0x7af93000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmwservices.dll
0x7afa0000 - 0x7b036000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmwmathutil.dll
0x791b0000 - 0x791e3000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mpath.dll
0x7b500000 - 0x7b515000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mlutil.dll
0x75620000 - 0x7569b000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x74b50000 - 0x74b61000     C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x78550000 - 0x7856a000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\bridge.dll
0x7a870000 - 0x7a87e000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmex.dll
0x795e0000 - 0x79638000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_dispatcher.dll
0x78570000 - 0x7858c000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\datasvcs.dll
0x78a30000 - 0x78bf2000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\xerces-c_2_7.dll
0x79c90000 - 0x7a1a0000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_interpreter.dll
0x78590000 - 0x785b1000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmat.dll
0x7abc0000 - 0x7ac85000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libhdf5.dll
0x794f0000 - 0x79539000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\profiler.dll
0x7a8d0000 - 0x7a8d9000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmwmathrng.dll
0x78600000 - 0x78612000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_pcodeio.dll
0x79170000 - 0x791a4000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_ir.dll
0x797c0000 - 0x79c8b000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_parser.dll
0x7a860000 - 0x7a86d000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\ir_xfmr.dll
0x782e0000 - 0x78411000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mcos.dll
0x7a900000 - 0x7a90a000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mtok.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=32M -Xms64m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:MaxPermSize=64M -Xmx128m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1200000000 -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Xshare:off -Xrs -Djava.library.path=e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32 vfprintf abort
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02
CLASSPATH=.;E:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Teleca Shared;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;E:\Program Files\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\cvsnt;e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin;e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32;
USERNAME=Administrator
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 family 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2

Memory: 4k page, physical 2095060k(531652k free), swap 4190120k(1770128k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105) for windows-x86, built on Nov 29 2006 00:48:48 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1310
```

Comment: you might want to share the contents of that `hs_err_pid10960.log` with the rest of us

Comment: code? error log? some useful information would be nice.

Comment: The most I can say without more information is that an unexpected error has been detected by the JRE.

Comment: I think the problem of mine is similar as this one.http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/251694 . However, I don't get the idea of it.

Answer (score 1):

Line 8 of your listing shows that your program fails in a native library named `jvm.dll` when invoking code at offset `0x3427`. The execution stack trace starts in line 57, and builds up; line 42 is the same fatal error. The rest describes the processor state at the time.

This can happen if the shared library is not the one expected by the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). Matlab's representation of `Float` may have changed between versions; you may need to check your installation.

For comparison, a similar analysis is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6673044/230513); line number are shown below.

```
     1      #
     2      # An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
     3      #
     4      #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x65a83427, pid=2864, tid=4760
     5      #
     6      # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105 mixed mode)
     7      # Problematic frame:
     8      # C  [jvm.dll+0x3427]
     9      #
    10      # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    11      #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    12      #
    13      
    14      ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
    15      
    16      Current thread (0x0840d800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4760]
    17      
    18      siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000164
    19      
    20      Registers:
    21      EAX=0x00000002, EBX=0x0840d8e8, ECX=0x0840d7c0, EDX=0x00000002
    22      ESP=0x0a6de4d4, EBP=0x0a6de4d8, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x082e0ca0
    23      EIP=0x65a83427, EFLAGS=0x00010246
    24      
    25      Top of Stack: (sp=0x0a6de4d4)
    26      0x0a6de4d4:   00000000 0a6de4fc 65b483e0 00000000
    27      0x0a6de4e4:   00000006 082e0ca0 0840d8e8 00000000
    28      0x0a6de4f4:   082ea3c0 00000000 0a6de518 786a1463
    29      0x0a6de504:   0840d8e8 082e0ca0 0840d800 180942f8
    30      0x0a6de514:   180942f8 0a6de554 0a84a460 0840d8e8
    31      0x0a6de524:   0a6de55c 0a6de564 00000007 78e6a575
    32      0x0a6de534:   0a6de534 180942f8 0a6de564 18100630
    33      0x0a6de544:   00000000 180942f8 00000000 0a6de564 
    34      
    35      Instructions: (pc=0x65a83427)
    36      0x65a83417:   64 01 00 00 5e 5d c3 cc cc 55 8b ec 56 8b 75 08
    37      0x65a83427:   c7 86 64 01 00 00 05 00 00 00 83 3d 58 ce d6 65 
    38      
    39      
    40      Stack: [0x09ee0000,0x0a6e0000),  sp=0x0a6de4d4,  free space=8185k
    41      Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    42      C  [jvm.dll+0x3427]
    43      C  [jvm.dll+0xc83e0]
    44      C  0x786a1463
    45      j  java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
    46      j  java.lang.Float.()V+2
    47      v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    48      
    49      Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    50      j  java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
    51      j  java.lang.Float.()V+2
    52      v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    53      j  java.util.HashMap.(IF)V+56
    54      j  java.util.HashMap.(I)V+4
    55      j  sun.misc.SoftCache.(I)V+26
    56      j  java.lang.Thread.()V+28
    57      v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    58      
    59      ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
    60      
    61      Java Threads: ( => current thread )
    62      =>0x0840d800 JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4760]
    63      
    64      Other Threads:
    65        0x08363c00 VMThread [id=1460]
    66      
    67      VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
    68      
    69      VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None
    70      
    71      Heap
    72       def new generation   total 14784K, used 263K [0x10080000, 0x11080000, 0x12080000)
    73        eden space 13184K,   2% used [0x10080000, 0x100c1ec8, 0x10d60000)
    74        from space 1600K,   0% used [0x10d60000, 0x10d60000, 0x10ef0000)
    75        to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x10ef0000, 0x10ef0000, 0x11080000)
    76       tenured generation   total 49152K, used 0K [0x12080000, 0x15080000, 0x18080000)
    77         the space 49152K,   0% used [0x12080000, 0x12080000, 0x12080200, 0x15080000)
    78       compacting perm gen  total 32768K, used 518K [0x18080000, 0x1a080000, 0x1c080000)
    79         the space 32768K,   1% used [0x18080000, 0x18101a00, 0x18101a00, 0x1a080000)
    80      No shared spaces configured.
    81      
    82      Dynamic libraries:
    83      0x00e20000 - 0x00e4f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    84      0x76f80000 - 0x770bc000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    85      0x76db0000 - 0x76e84000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
    86      0x75190000 - 0x751da000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
    87      0x768e0000 - 0x76980000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
    88      0x75ae0000 - 0x75b8c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
    89      0x76cf0000 - 0x76d09000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
    90      0x76c40000 - 0x76ce1000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
    91      0x770e0000 - 0x771a9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
    92      0x754f0000 - 0x7553e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
    93      0x754e0000 - 0x754ea000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
    94      0x76d10000 - 0x76dad000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
    95      0x74050000 - 0x741ee000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
    96      0x76f20000 - 0x76f77000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
    97      0x768c0000 - 0x768df000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
    98      0x75410000 - 0x754dc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
    99      0x659c0000 - 0x65a7e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
   100      0x65a80000 - 0x65da8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
   101      0x70ab0000 - 0x70ab7000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
   102      0x755d0000 - 0x75605000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
   103      0x770d0000 - 0x770d6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
   104      0x738d0000 - 0x73902000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
   105      0x770c0000 - 0x770c5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
   106      0x68180000 - 0x6818c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
   107      0x68160000 - 0x68180000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
   108      0x659a0000 - 0x659b3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
   109      0x6b490000 - 0x6b5d2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\awt.dll
   110      0x75540000 - 0x755cf000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   111      0x757c0000 - 0x7591c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
   112      0x73ac0000 - 0x73ad3000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
   113      0x73db0000 - 0x73df0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
   114      0x6c530000 - 0x6c539000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Spigot\Search Settings\wth.dll
   115      0x70ac0000 - 0x70b63000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCR90.dll
   116      0x10000000 - 0x1007c000     E:\Program Files\DigitalPersona\Bin\DpoFeedb.dll
   117      0x74720000 - 0x74737000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
   118      0x75110000 - 0x7511b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
   119      0x75060000 - 0x7506c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
   120      0x04380000 - 0x043db000     E:\Program Files\DigitalPersona\Bin\DpoSet.dll
   121      0x69370000 - 0x69533000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
   122      0x745c0000 - 0x745c9000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
   123      0x6c140000 - 0x6c146000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
   124      0x68bf0000 - 0x69369000     C:\Windows\system32\nvd3dum.dll
   125      0x74020000 - 0x74045000     C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll
   126      0x76aa0000 - 0x76c3d000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
   127      0x752a0000 - 0x752c7000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
   128      0x753f0000 - 0x75402000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
   129      0x75bf0000 - 0x7683a000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   130      0x70d50000 - 0x70dd4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
   131      0x61d90000 - 0x61dba000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\fontmanager.dll
   132      0x656f0000 - 0x65704000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
   133      0x74b70000 - 0x74bac000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
   134      0x74b40000 - 0x74b46000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
   135      0x656e0000 - 0x656ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
   136      0x72e30000 - 0x72e61000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\t2k.dll
   137      0x75010000 - 0x7505c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
   138      0x76e90000 - 0x76f13000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
   139      0x06eb0000 - 0x07048000     C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
   140      0x73ee0000 - 0x73fd5000     C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
   141      0x73420000 - 0x73441000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
   142      0x76840000 - 0x76885000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
   143      0x6e740000 - 0x6e76e000     C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll
   144      0x73140000 - 0x7314a000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
   145      0x70580000 - 0x70592000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
   146      0x716c0000 - 0x716c8000     C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
   147      0x75070000 - 0x75099000     C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
   148      0x716e0000 - 0x716f4000     C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
   149      0x6d960000 - 0x6d977000     C:\Windows\System32\davclnt.dll
   150      0x6cda0000 - 0x6cda8000     C:\Windows\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
   151      0x74960000 - 0x7496f000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
   152      0x701f0000 - 0x701fb000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
   153      0x74b30000 - 0x74b39000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
   154      0x71f30000 - 0x72168000     C:\Windows\system32\wpdshext.dll
   155      0x73c20000 - 0x73db0000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17825_none_72d273598668a06b\gdiplus.dll
   156      0x6dde0000 - 0x6de69000     C:\Windows\system32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
   157      0x75270000 - 0x7529d000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
   158      0x752d0000 - 0x753ed000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
   159      0x75180000 - 0x7518c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
   160      0x72d90000 - 0x72dcf000     C:\Windows\system32\audiodev.dll
   161      0x61640000 - 0x618a7000     C:\Windows\system32\WMVCore.DLL
   162      0x72b10000 - 0x72b4d000     C:\Windows\system32\WMASF.DLL
   163      0x6e9c0000 - 0x6e9f1000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
   164      0x6cd70000 - 0x6cd92000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorAPI.dll
   165      0x73990000 - 0x73a8b000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
   166      0x00990000 - 0x009a7000     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt.14.dll
   167      0x6fc90000 - 0x6fd7b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
   168      0x7c3a0000 - 0x7c41b000     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\MSVCP71.dll
   169      0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\MSVCR71.dll
   170      0x6e950000 - 0x6e9ba000     C:\Windows\System32\cscui.dll
   171      0x6e940000 - 0x6e949000     C:\Windows\System32\CSCDLL.dll
   172      0x6e8d0000 - 0x6e940000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
   173      0x74f50000 - 0x74f69000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
   174      0x088a0000 - 0x08a06000     E:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\nativemcl.dll
   175      0x7ad60000 - 0x7adb2000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmx.dll
   176      0x7ac90000 - 0x7ad5b000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libut.dll
   177      0x76890000 - 0x768ba000     C:\Windows\system32\imagehlp.dll
   178      0x7b4d0000 - 0x7b4ef000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\LIBEXPAT.dll
   179      0x70cb0000 - 0x70d4b000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\MSVCR80.dll
   180      0x7b040000 - 0x7b117000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icuuc36.dll
   181      0x7a820000 - 0x7a824000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icudt36.dll
   182      0x7a830000 - 0x7a83c000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icuio36.dll
   183      0x7aaf0000 - 0x7abb2000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\icuin36.dll
   184      0x70a20000 - 0x70aa7000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\MSVCP80.dll
   185      0x78680000 - 0x78692000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\zlib1.dll
   186      0x08240000 - 0x082be000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mclmcr.dll
   187      0x79710000 - 0x79746000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mcr.dll
   188      0x7a840000 - 0x7a857000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\iqm.dll
   189      0x7adc0000 - 0x7af93000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmwservices.dll
   190      0x7afa0000 - 0x7b036000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmwmathutil.dll
   191      0x791b0000 - 0x791e3000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mpath.dll
   192      0x7b500000 - 0x7b515000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mlutil.dll
   193      0x75620000 - 0x7569b000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
   194      0x74b50000 - 0x74b61000     C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
   195      0x78550000 - 0x7856a000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\bridge.dll
   196      0x7a870000 - 0x7a87e000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmex.dll
   197      0x795e0000 - 0x79638000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_dispatcher.dll
   198      0x78570000 - 0x7858c000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\datasvcs.dll
   199      0x78a30000 - 0x78bf2000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\xerces-c_2_7.dll
   200      0x79c90000 - 0x7a1a0000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_interpreter.dll
   201      0x78590000 - 0x785b1000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmat.dll
   202      0x7abc0000 - 0x7ac85000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libhdf5.dll
   203      0x794f0000 - 0x79539000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\profiler.dll
   204      0x7a8d0000 - 0x7a8d9000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\libmwmathrng.dll
   205      0x78600000 - 0x78612000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_pcodeio.dll
   206      0x79170000 - 0x791a4000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_ir.dll
   207      0x797c0000 - 0x79c8b000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\m_parser.dll
   208      0x7a860000 - 0x7a86d000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\ir_xfmr.dll
   209      0x782e0000 - 0x78411000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mcos.dll
   210      0x7a900000 - 0x7a90a000     e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mtok.dll
   211      
   212      VM Arguments:
   213      jvm_args: -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=32M -Xms64m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:MaxPermSize=64M -Xmx128m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1200000000 -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Xshare:off -Xrs -Djava.library.path=e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32 vfprintf abort
   214      java_command: 
   215      Launcher Type: generic
   216      
   217      Environment Variables:
   218      JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02
   219      CLASSPATH=.;E:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
   220      PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Teleca Shared;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;E:\Program Files\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\cvsnt;e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin;e:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32;
   221      USERNAME=Administrator
   222      OS=Windows_NT
   223      PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
   224      
   225      
   226      
   227      ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
   228      
   229      OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7601 Service Pack 1
   230      
   231      CPU:total 2 family 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2
   232      
   233      Memory: 4k page, physical 2095060k(531652k free), swap 4190120k(1770128k free)
   234      
   235      vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105) for windows-x86, built on Nov 29 2006 00:48:48 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1310
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And I think the JRE is the problem.